# show/hide div using jquery and c#

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show/hide three divs based on jquery using `<a href="#id">`. But the code is not working. The code works fine when I map using `<a>` link using rel attribute.

For example: `<a rel="cat1" class="selected">`

## Default.aspx

```
<div id="featuredleftdiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var featuredposts = new ddtabcontent("featuredposts")
        featuredposts.setpersist(true)
        featuredposts.setselectedClassTarget("link")
        featuredposts.init(10000)
    </script>

    <ul id="featuredposts" class="featuredposts">
        <li><a href="#cat1" class="menu">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cat2" class="menu">b</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="cat1" class="featuredposts_content">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView4" runat="server" GroupItemCount="1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="ListView4_PagePropertiesChanging"></asp:ListView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>  

    <div id="cat2" class="featuredposts_content">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView5" runat="server" GroupItemCount="1"  OnPagePropertiesChanging="ListView4_PagePropertiesChanging"></asp:ListView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

## JQuery

In Head section of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.menu").click(function () {
        $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the code is not working", please try to explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: why `$($(this).attr('href')).show();` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mC23h/ - looks to be working for me.

Comment: @lante - it's to tell which div id to show from the href...basically it's saying $('#cat1').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
​<html>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("a.menu").click(function () {
            $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
            $("#" + $(this).attr("value")).show();
         });​
      })
   </script>
   <body>
      <ul id="featuredposts" class="featuredposts">
         <li><a href="#" class="menu" value="IdOfDiv1">something a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="menu" value="IdOfDiv2">something b</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="IdOfDiv1" class="featuredposts_content">
         Cat1
      </div>  

      <div id="IdOfDiv2" class="featuredposts_content">
         Cat2
      </div>
  </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

EDIT:
Here's a quick explanation.

The `$(document).ready()` will make sure the wiring of the click does not happen until the page is fully loaded.  When the page first loads, everything is being displayed.

Once a user clicks on one of the links with class of `menu`, the function will run.  It will hide every `div` that have the class of `featuredposts_content`.  Then, based on which link was clicked, it grabs the `value` and use that in setting which `div` to show.  The `value` in the link is the `id` of the `div` to show.

Comment: Can you explain this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning event handlers before the elements exist on the page.  Change the script in the head section to this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a.menu").click(function () {
            $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
            $($(this).attr('href')).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `$(function() { })` code makes your script run when the document is ready, or when all the elements have been created.

Comment: But OP mentioned it works with "rel", so it should have same effect, i.e, not having events attached.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **Update panels** are messing it up.

You need to bind the event after every postback , otherwise it gets set back to the default page

```
$(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(PostBack);
    PostBack();
});

function PostBack(){
       $("a.menu").off().on.('click' , function () {
            $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
            $($(this).attr('href')).show();
            return false;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i think issue is the not using the doc ready handler or load function for the events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ // <-------------------------you are missing this
    $("a.menu").click(function () {
        $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        return false;
    });
   }); //<----------------------------------------------------
</script>
```